# Is it correct to say "do you attend this year"

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

I replied to an email recently with the text `do you attend this year summer training sessions?` to which one of my friend told me that this sentence is incorrect. Can somebody help me with what's wrong with the sentence?

My intention was to ask the message-author in a mixed mood where I am angry but have to ask politely, if the person has been even attending the classes?

Comment: In addition to the given answer by John, you can also ask, "do you attend this year's summer training sessions?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The order is wrong.

Normally, this would be written as

> Do you attend summer training sessions this year?

Nouns and noun phrases that are used to indicate time ("yesterday", "this year", "tomorrow", etc.) are generally placed after the object of the sentence, not after the verb.

> I saw a film yesterday.
>
> I'm throwing a birthday party for my daughter tomorrow.

Answer (score 3):

I think in this case you may want to say, "Have you been attending this year's summer training?" or "Have you been attending summer training this year?" I don't think you want to say "Do you attend."

When you say "Do you" in the present tense, it implies a general habit, like *do you usually attend summer training sessions* as a habitual act. If you want to talk about something that is currently taking place, or should have been taking place until now, you will use the perfect tense like *have you been attending* up until now, or the present tense *are you attending* now and within close proximity to now.

Both *are you attending* and *have you been attending* will convey the tone you described.